Mrs. Perkins' Quilt Problem
I have gotten interested in square packing problems recently and I came across a problem called the Mrs. Perkins' Quilt Problem. But I have had some trouble understanding it.
To state the conditions of the problem strictly, we can write this (taken from an online article):
The dissection of a square of side into a number of smaller squares. Unlike a Perfect Square Dissection, however, the smaller Squares need not be all different sizes. In addition, only prime dissections are considered so that patterns which can be dissected on lower order Squares are not permitted. The smallest number of Relatively Prime dissections of a quilt for 1, 2, ..., are 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, ...
I'm unable to understand what we mean exactly by the term Prime Dissection. Take the case of a square of edge length 6. Clearly, here we use squares of sizes 4,2,1. But 4 can be broken down into squares of 4 squares of size 2.
Here is how solving the problem for a square of size 6 looks like.
The condition states what there must not be any patterns in lower order squares, which is that prevents the breaking down of the square of size 4 that I mentioned before.
Any inputs that will help me understand this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Wikipedia says that you just need there not to have all the small square sizes have a common factor, so doubling your $6 \times 6$ solution to get a dissection of a $12 \times 12$ square into an $8 \times 8, 4 \ 4\times 4s \text { and } 4 \ 2 \times 2s$  would not be acceptable.
